# How to configure client server setup for Bio-metric(Fingerprint) in a web application

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-boot, biometrics

We have a Java and Spring based application, and need to configure client-server setup for Bio-metric(Fingerprint).

We are using "Hamster DX" fingerprint scanner which is a product of NITGEN biometric solutions model: HFDU06

We tried https://webapi.secugen.com/ API, and followed all instructions but couldn't succeed.

Any solutions OR suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Biometric service provider should have their own development kit to connect and send authentication response. Check with supplier.